# git commit in vscode with the standard template

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After running `git commit` an editor opens and there a template for the commit message:

```
<empty line where the messgae should come>
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch mybranch
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mybranch'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   README.md
#       deleted:    README.rst
#       modified:   foo.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#       bar.txt
#
```

Then a common practice is to provide a short one-liner, an empty line and a longer optional description of the commit. When using vscode I noticed that `git: commit` only allows one line message (`enter` is actually the committing).

Is there some command in vscode which opens a new buffer with the template known from the CLI of git and upon saving(!) of this new buffer the commit will happen?

Comment: Multiline messages work fine for me in vscode. cmd+enter or ctrl+enter does the actual commit, and <enter> inserts a newline like you'd expect. What OS?

Comment: I'm using macOS and cmd+enter and shift+enter execute the commit and NOT inserting a new line. Furthermore, I am interested in seeing the list of changes in the commit similar to the comments in the default template.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to `git commit` in VS Code:

1. With empty message box in the source control side bar *Git:Commit* in Command Palette or clicking *Commit* check-mark will give you an input box where you can input one line, <enter> commits, that's the situation you are describing.
2. You can type multi-line message and then commit via Command Palette or check-mark.
3. From integrated terminal `git commit` without message will give you template message in your default editor. It's vi usually, but you can configure git to use any editor.

Comment: Does the check-mark commit all or just staged changes?

Comment: @mchammer it commits just the staged changes. You can stage files by clicking the "+" mark when hovering over them in the `git` window. You can also stage ALL files by hovering over "changes" at the top and clicking the "+" mark.